# Comment Section UI Problem

Tags: bug, comments, user-interface

Today, I added one comment with some code that I copied from my Webstorm IDE so I don't need to write it here, and boom, I don't know why the UI is spoiled but just I want to inform Stackoverflow devs, so they can take care of it. I also noticed that the bug is only coming in **Chrome**.

**Chrome**

> [image]

**Firefox**

> [image]

Post: [How can I remove the base address from an assigned url in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71299846/how-can-i-remove-the-base-address-from-an-assigned-url-in-react?noredirect=1#comment126030494_71299846)